# Why are these values showing null?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have three tables. [C# windows form, ms sql server]

CustomerTable:

------Id

------Name

DressTypeTable

------DressTypeId

------Name

MeasurementDetailsTable

------Id

------DressTypeId

------Details

------CustomerId

I want to retrieve [ using customerId]

Customer Name

DressType Name

Measurement Details.

I'm using this query below:

```
 _aMeasurementDetails = new MeasurementDetails();
        _connection.Open();
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM MeasurementDetailsTable where CustomerId='{0}'", id);
        _command = new SqlCommand(query, _connection);
        SqlDataReader aReader = _command.ExecuteReader();


        if (aReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (aReader.Read())
            {
                _aMeasurementDetails.MeasurementDetailsId = (int)aReader[0];
                _aMeasurementDetails.DressType.DressTypeId = (int)aReader[1];
                _aMeasurementDetails.Details = (string)aReader[2];
                _aMeasurementDetails.Customer.CustomerId = (int)aReader[3];
            }
        }
        _connection.Close();
        return _aMeasurementDetails;
```

When I want to retrieve value using CustomerId it shows "Object reference set to an instance of an object". It can not retrieve data from

```
 _aMeasurementDetails.DressType.DressTypeId = (int)aReader[1];
```

and

```
  _aMeasurementDetails.Customer.CustomerId = (int)aReader[3];
```

But when I'm executing the query in the ms sql server, it can retrieve the data! How to solve this problem?

Here is my MeasurementDetails Model Class

```
 public int MeasurementDetailsId { get; set; }
    public String Details { get; set; }
    public DressType DressType { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

Here is my MeasurementDetails Manager Class

```
 private MeasurementDetailsGateway aMeasurementDetailsGateway;
    public bool SaveMeasurementDetails(Model.MeasurementDetails aMeasurementDetails)
    {
        aMeasurementDetailsGateway = new MeasurementDetailsGateway();
        return aMeasurementDetailsGateway.SaveMeasurementDetails(aMeasurementDetails);
    }

    public Model.MeasurementDetails GetMeasurementDetailsUsingCustomerInfo(int id)
    {
        aMeasurementDetailsGateway = new MeasurementDetailsGateway();
        return aMeasurementDetailsGateway.GetMeasurementDetailsUsingCustomerInfo(id);
    }
```

Here is my MeasurementDetails Gateway class

```
private SqlConnection _connection;
    private SqlCommand _command;
    private MeasurementDetails _aMeasurementDetails;

    public MeasurementDetailsGateway()
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection();
        _connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TailorShopDB"].ConnectionString;
    }
    public bool SaveMeasurementDetails(Model.MeasurementDetails aMeasurementDetails)
    {
        _connection.Open();
        string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO MeasurementDetailsTable values ('{0}','{1}', '{2}')", 
            aMeasurementDetails.DressType.DressTypeId, aMeasurementDetails.Details, aMeasurementDetails.Customer.CustomerId);

        _command = new SqlCommand(query, _connection);
        int affectedRows = _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _connection.Close();
        if (affectedRows > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Model.MeasurementDetails GetMeasurementDetailsUsingCustomerInfo(int id)
    {

        _aMeasurementDetails = new MeasurementDetails();
        _connection.Open();
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM MeasurementDetailsTable where CustomerId='{0}'", id);
        _command = new SqlCommand(query, _connection);
        SqlDataReader aReader = _command.ExecuteReader();


        if (aReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (aReader.Read())
            {
                _aMeasurementDetails.MeasurementDetailsId = (int)aReader[0];
                _aMeasurementDetails.DressType.DressTypeId = (int)aReader["DressTypeId"];
                _aMeasurementDetails.Details = (string)aReader[2];
                _aMeasurementDetails.Customer.CustomerId = (int)aReader["CustomerId"];
            }
        }
        _connection.Close();
        return _aMeasurementDetails;
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug and see what is the exact query being generated, and then run that on server?

Comment: For starters... your reader, you should probably use the name of the field, not just the index. That may help you detect a field you are missing. You could be off

Comment: Put your breakpoint on   if (aReader.HasRows) and see if it even HAS ROWS. If it doesnt than you are either not connecting to the right SQL server or you are not querying exactly the same as MS_SQL

Comment: @shree.pat18 Yes, I debugged. I execute the query (in the ms sql server ) I got from debug, and it works perfect.

Comment: @logixologist Has Rows returns true

Comment: Are DressType and Customer and Details instantiated when you instantiate a new object of MeasurementDetails?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I'm not using _aDressType.DressTypeId / _aCustomer.CustomerId. So, if I instantiate those, those will be unreachable code, right? As I'm using _aMeasurementDetails.DressType.DressTypeId and _aMeasurementDetails.Customer.CustomerId. and yes, I've instantiated MeasurementDetails

Comment: Please show your MeasurementDetails class. 100% sure that @AllanS.Hansen is right.

Comment: By the way: please use parameters in your query. Do not build the value into the string - that will lead to "sql injection" exploits.

Comment: @HansKesting You are right. I will use parameters in my query.

Comment: You are using a `while` loop to write to a single object. This seems like a mismatch to me. (OK, when you query by ID, you probably get at most a single record - so not a big problem in this case)

Comment: please add **relevant code**! The `Gateway` class is redundant information, because you've already posted the faulting code. Also, you still haven't posted the `MeasurementDetails` class. Sure, you posted the Properties, but if the constructor isn't doing `DressType = new DressType();` you'll won't be able to access anything *in* DressType property (which is what Allan S. Hansen asked about) because it will be `null`.

Comment: @HansKesting Oh! There will be several rows for the same customer.

Comment: @Default I've posted MeasurementDetails (Model) class. Isn't it MeasurementDetails class? I've posted again the full class to make sure that I've instantiated the MeasurementDetails class in the gateway class too.

Comment: Well as I said @AllanS.Hansen is right. Create DressType, Customer instances in MeasurementDetails constructor or before you trying to access those type properties.

Comment: @Reniuz in MeasurementDetails, I've included public DressType DressType {get; set;} and public Customer Customer {get; set;}. Why should I use them in the constructor? Sorry I don't understand this part. Can you show me how to?

Comment: @mmahbub please post full class, or at least the constructor. If no constructor exists, see if it helps by adding one and doing `DressType = new DressType(); Customer = new Customer();`.

Comment: @Default I have posted the full class! Where should I use DressType = new DressType();? Customer = new Customer();? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: You should learn what is property, and what is reference types. Its basic things.

Comment: I rolled back your question. If you need to ask additional questions ask a new question. Don't add new questions to already established questions. It renders the current discussions and answers obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the class you are instantiating sets its properties to their respective [default values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx). If you examine `_aMeasurementDetails` in the debugger after this line:

```
_aMeasurementDetails = new MeasurementDetails();
```

You will see that `DressType` and `Customer` are `null`.

Since the default value for `DressType` and `Customer` is `null` you cannot access their respective properties. You have to instantiate these properties before accessing them, which can be done in some different ways.

Via constructor:

```
public class MeasurementDetails{
    ....
    public MeasurementDetails(){
        Customer = new Customer();
        DressType = new DressType();
        ....
    }
}
```

via the class that uses `MeasurementDetails`

```
_aMeasurementDetails = new MeasurementDetails();
_aMeasurementDetails.Customer = new Customer();
_aMeasurementDetails.DressType = new DressType();
```

or you can initialize it when you're fetching the values.

```
MeasurementDetails _aMeasurementDetails;

_aMeasurementDetails = new MeasurementDetails {
    MeasurementDetailsId = (int)aReader[0],
    DressType = { DressTypeId = (int)aReader[1] },
    Details = (string)aReader[2],
    Customer = { CustomerId = (int)aReader[3] }
}
```

Comment: It removes the errors now! Thanks. But How can I retrieve DressType Name and Customer Name? It does not retrieve them! Only dressTypeId can be retrieved! I've included the UI code above.

Comment: It's right there in your tables - `MeasurementDetailsTable` contains neither `DressTypeName` or `CustomerName`. You'd have to fetch them as well, from their respective tables.

Comment: But I'm using a foreign key here. How can I fetch them?! I'm saving DressType info into DressType table, Customer Info into Customer tables and made two foreign keys into MeasurementDetails Table.

Comment: I guess a join between the tables, and then modifying your `aReader[i]` indexes, something like. `select * from MeasurementDetailsTable join CustomerTable on MeasurementDetailsTable.CustomerId = Customer.Id join DressTypeTable on MeasurementDetailsTable.DressTypeId = DressType.Id`. If you require additional information about fetching related data I suggest asking a new question about that.